How can I use Bash to listen to multiple input devices on Linux?
I'm trying to write a shell script to wait for input from any one of multiple devices, then from the input event determine which button was pressed and which device it came from.
In my case I want to get controller/joystick input, i.e., /dev/input/js0, /dev/input/js1 etc. For example print "press start to play", and then get the device path of first controller to respond.
I have found the below command using jstest, but it this does not work with multiple devices.
$ jstest --event /dev/input/js0 | grep -m 1 "type 1, time .*, number .*, value 1"
Event: type 1, time 2697465, number 0, value 1


There is the showkey command. See: https://superuser.com/a/248568 for example

You could for each device create a background process which listens to one particular device, and then wait in the main program, until the first one finishes.

@user1934428 Thanks for this suggestion, I've come up with a solution based on this and it works exactly how I need.

Update: As per @jhnc's advice I've improved this by not parsing the output of ls
Following @user1934428's suggestion to use a background process and wait, I came up with this solution.
# loop through joystick devices
for device in /dev/input/js*
do
    # use jstest and grep to capture the start button (number 7)
    jstest --event $device | grep -m 1 "type 1, time .*, number 7, value 1" &
done

# wait for at least one of the background processes to finish then kill the others
wait -n
kill $(jobs -p)

The below questions/answers also helped in coming up with this solution

Using a shell script with jstest, how can I get a gamepad to interact with my script?
WAIT for "1 of many process" to finish


that code doesn't quite do what you intend. grep js* matches either anything containing j, js, jss, jsss, etc, OR anything with the same name as a file in the current directory whose name begins with js (if there is one such filename) OR ignores ls output and looks for the filename of one such file in the others (if there are many such filenames).  it might be simpler to do shopt -s nullglob; for device_path in /dev/input/js*; do jstest ...

The correct grep command would be grep '^js.*$' or just grep ^js (in case there are devices containing js somewhere else other than at the start). Someone will be along shortly to tell you not to parse ls output.

Thanks @jhnc, I've updated my answer.
